# Automating a Workstation with multiple users

Tags: automation, automated-tests, enterprise, testcomplete, multiple-users

We have an Enterprise product installed in a windows server machine where the requirement is to login to the machine with the different set of users at a time and access the application.
We are using Test complete for automation and i have tried to achieve this by distributed testing where we can configure multiple hosts and run at a time.The problem is Test complete will not allow RDP into multiple users on a same VM. only one user for 1 Host.

Any idea of achieving my workflow..? Test Complete dont have option to do that.Any other tools or ways to achieve my test plan?

Comment: Do you have to test all users simultaneously or can you check the user profiles sequentially?

Comment: Like distributed testing, we will have same test with set of users. If we run suite, at time it has to login to the system with different set of users and run the script.

Comment: So if your main concern is just to test the user roles, then you can test them one after another - change the roles in backend db and restart your app. Unless you have to restart your server, a change in db should be enough and you can do this using testcomplete.